# Flutter Navigator "argument type 'Context' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'BuildContext'"

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to pass my menuButton category Names to the next page and have that set the state of the next page on my categoryScreens.

Currently I am receiving a red squiggly line with a note of "argument type 'Context' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'BuildContext'"

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:boardwalk/Screens/categoryScreen.dart';
import 'package:boardwalk/Widgets/headerCategory.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';

class homeMenu extends StatelessWidget {
  const homeMenu({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  Padding menuButton(String category, IconData categoryIcon) {
    return Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
        child: Container(
          width: 95,
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: ()=>
              Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => categoryScreen()));
            ,
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Center(
                  child: Container(
                    height: 70,
                    width: 70,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      gradient: LinearGradient(
                        colors: [Colors.deepPurple, Colors.deepPurpleAccent],
                      ),
                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    ),
                    child: Icon(
                      categoryIcon,
                      size: 40.0,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
                  child: Text(
                    category,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
                      fontSize: 14,
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
      child: Container(
        height: 100,
        width: 400,
        child: ListView(scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal, children: <Widget>[
          menuButton('Home', Icons.home),
          menuButton('Eat', Icons.restaurant_menu),
          menuButton('Shop', Icons.store),
          menuButton('Travel', Icons.airplanemode_active),
          menuButton('Play', Icons.local_activity),
          menuButton('Service', Icons.build),
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I am not sure what to be passing in the navigator if it does not like context, I am completely unsure of what is expecting at this point.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Actually, the issue is caused by importing the path.dart package. To fix this, change context to this.context

Comment: How could you discover that !

Answer (score 3):

A Widget does not have access to the `BuildContext` outside the `build` method. If you are creating the a reusable Widget function like `menuButton` here, then you have to pass in the `BuildContext` instance you receive in the `build` method.

So your code becomes,

```dart
class homeMenu extends StatelessWidget {
  const homeMenu({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  Padding menuButton(BuildContext context, String category, IconData categoryIcon, BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
        ...
        );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
      child: Container(
        height: 100,
        width: 400,
        child: ListView(scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal, children: <Widget>[
          menuButton(context, 'Home', Icons.home),
          ...
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I simply changed context to this.context and it solved the issue after 2 hours of looking for a solution!